# replace `getIntVolatile(Object var1, long var2)` with `getInt(Object var1, long var2)` in the implementation of incrementAndGet() in java

Tags: java, atomic, volatile

According the jdk ,the implementation of the method incrementAndGet() of AtomicInteger class is as follows:

```
public final int incrementAndGet() {
    return unsafe.getAndAddInt(this, valueOffset, 1) + 1;
}
```

```
public final int getAndAddInt(Object var1, long var2, int var4) {
    int var5;
    do {
        var5 = this.getIntVolatile(var1, var2);
    } while(!this.compareAndSwapInt(var1, var2, var5, var5 + var4));

    return var5;
}
```

What happens if the `getIntVolatile(Object var1, long var2)` method is replaced by `getInt(Object var1, long var2)` method?

What I think is that the `getIntVolatile(Object var1, long var2)` method is unnecessary, as the operated variable is a volatile variable，the `getInt(Object var1, long var2)` is able to read the latest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what `incrementAndGet` does:

```
return unsafe.getAndAddInt(this, valueOffset, 1) + 1;
```

`unsafe` has no idea that at the `valueOffset` there is a `volatile` field and it must treat it as such. So, this (I am not using `var2` and the like, but the real source code):

```
v = getIntVolatile(o, offset);
```

surely looks like protects against some possible re-orderings. Let's say you replace that `getIntVolatile` with `getInt`:

```
 do {
      v = getInt(o, offset);
 } while (!weakCompareAndSetInt(o, offset, v, v + delta));
```

Since there are no volatile semantics here, the compiler can move the read out of the loop:

```
 int v = getInt(o, offset);
 do {
 } while (!weakCompareAndSetInt(o, offset, v, v + delta));
```

If it does that, you can end-up in an infinite loop, pretty trivially.

Answer (score 1):

Plain `getXXX`/`putXXX` methods in the `Unsafe` class, do not take the `volatile` keyword into account. They always perform a plain load/store, without memory visibility constraints.